# Выборка Nраз из бд mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите как сделать выборку из базы данных MySQL определенных категории по 8 товаров.

Таблица

> ID|CAT|NAME|DESCRIPTION|

CAT - от 1 до 7, выбрать по 8 товаров каждой категории

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) num
FROM MY_TABLE t1 JOIN MY_TABLE t2
ON t1.CAT = t2.CAT AND t1.ID >= t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.CAT, t1.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 8
ORDER BY CAT, ID
```

Comment: Спасибо, ближе к тому что мне надо